# Spring Security Basic Authentication returns 404

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to migrate my Spring Security XML configuration to Java config. 
The XML config simply uses Basic Auth:

```
<beans:beans ...>

    <http create-session="stateless">
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <authentication-manager>
        ...
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

The Java config I have is also quite simple:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("...")
public class JavaSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        authorizeRequests().
        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
        httpBasic().and().
        sessionManagement().
        sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().
        csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

With the XML configuration - when I make an unauthenticated request - I get a 401 back as expected.

With Java config, I get back a 404 - and can't figure out why. 
I tried to follow the response back until it goes out of Tomcat and the status code - up until the very end - is 401. So the 404 is very surprising on the client side.

Finally - I tried entirely disabling my global exception handler (@ControllerAdvice) and it doesn't seem to be the root cause of the issue. 
Any idea what the problem might be?